# How to implement paging in gridview in a modular popup?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a modular popup to show gridview in a popup. Now I want to implement paging of this gridview. When I click on the page number the popup disappears. How do I avoid it? I want it to disappear only when clicking close button.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using the [`ModalPopupExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from the `AjaxControlToolkit`.

If you're posting back you always need to call `ModalPopupExtender1.Show()` in codebehind when you want it to stay visible.

You could simplify it by using `Page_PreRender` if you have many events and you don't want to remember this always:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // change "this" to somewhat appropriate for example your GridView
    // "this" makes sense for example in a UserControl
    if (this.Visible) {
        this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
}
```